# Change the colours of a bar chart to match data

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a bar chart but want to change the colours of each bar to match the continent.Data and code below

Code used;

```
 ggplot(life_bar, aes(x = reorder(Continent, -mn), y = mn)) + 
   geom_col() +
   ylab('Life Expectancy') +
   xlab('Continent')
```

Data;

```
life_bar
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Continent                mn
   <chr>                 <dbl>
1 Africa                 62.7
2 Americas               74.8
3 Eastern Mediterranean  71.3
4 Europe                 78.1
5 South-East Asia        71.6
6 Western Pacific        74.3
```

Comment: Put `fill = Continent` inside your `aes()` to set the fill color of the bars based on the Continent column.

Comment: While it appears you are using a dataset within a package, not everybody has this package, so it may be better to include a reproducible version of the data you are using. You can do so by using `dput`, which you can use following the steps here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg